# Bizarre fragment transaction Behavior

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

My app is behaving weirdly, I'm using a FrameLayout within my activity layout to inflate a fragment class, like so:

```
if (mapFragment == null) {
    mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    addFragment(mapFragment, null, MapFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
} else {
    addFragment(mapFragment, null, MapFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
}
```

The weird thing is the first time the user runs this code by clicking on a button my whole activity gets restarted and logically the fragment is no longer displayed. Here's the addFragment method:

```
void addFragment(Fragment frag, Bundle bundle, String backstack,
    boolean forceReplace, FragmentActivity _activity) {

    Log.e("Addfragment Method", "Fragment Added");
    FragmentManager fm = _activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(getRes());
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (bundle != null) {
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
    }
    if (fragment != null || forceReplace) {
        ft.replace(getRes(), frag, backstack);
        ft.addToBackStack(backstack);
        Log.e("replaced","fragment");
    } else {
        ft.add(getRes(), frag, backstack);
        ft.addToBackStack(backstack);
        Log.e("created","fragment");
    }
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

here is the fragment onCreateView method

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Utils.sendTrackerDetails(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

} catch (InflateException e) {

    }
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    mLayoutMap = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_map);
    mEmptyText = (CustomFontTextview) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
    mTextSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_text);

    mPocketBar = (SmoothProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pocket);
    mPocketBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new SmoothProgressDrawable.Builder(getActivity()).interpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).build());

    text_header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_header);
    search_text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    liste = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_dab);
    mTextSearch.setEnabled(false);

    if (Utils.checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability(getActivity()) || Utils.isConnectedTointernet(getActivity())) {
        //MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        if (mGoogleMap == null)
            initilizeMap();
        else {
            if (Status.equals(Constants.TAG_CLASS_DAB)) {
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.epingle_dab);
                mListDabAsynck = new LoadDABAsyncTask();
                mListDabAsynck.execute();
            } else {
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.epingle);
                mListAgenceAsynck = new LoadAgencesAsyncTask();
                mListAgenceAsynck.execute();
            }
        }


    } else {
        Utils.showErrorCrouton(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.text_service_nondisponible));
    }

    if (Status.equals(Constants.TAG_CLASS_DAB)) {

        text_header.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence));
        search_text.setHint(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence));

    } else {
        text_header.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence_banque));
        search_text.setHint(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence_banque));
    }


    btn_liste = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_liste);
    btn_liste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Status.equals(Constants.TAG_CLASS_AGENCE)) {

                mTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        String text = mTextSearch.getText().toString()
                                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                        if (!(listAgenceAdapter == null)) {
                            listAgenceAdapter.filter(text);
                            if (listAgenceAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                liste.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                liste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (tagName.equals("liste")) {
                    btn_liste.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_liste));
                    text_header.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence_banque));
                    flip(mLayoutMap, liste, DURATION);
                    liste.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tagName = "map";
                    mTextSearch.setEnabled(true);
                    mTextSearch.setText("");
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {

                    btn_liste.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_liste));
                    flip(liste, mLayoutMap, DURATION);
                    tagName = "liste";
                    mTextSearch.setEnabled(false);
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mTextSearch.setText("");
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {

                mTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        String text = mTextSearch.getText().toString()
                                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                        if (!(listDabAdapter == null)) {
                            listDabAdapter.filter(text);
                            if (listDabAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                liste.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                liste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (tagName.equals("liste")) {
                    btn_liste.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_map));
                    text_header.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.trouver_agence));
                    flip(mLayoutMap, liste, DURATION);
                    liste.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tagName = "map";
                    mTextSearch.setEnabled(true);
                    mTextSearch.setText("");
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    btn_liste.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_liste));
                    flip(liste, mLayoutMap, DURATION);
                    tagName = "liste";
                    mTextSearch.setEnabled(false);
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mTextSearch.setText("");
                    mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

onCreate method has basically a bunch of clikListeners

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = MainActivity.this;
    Log.e("activityCreated", "ActivityCreated");
    checkNewVersion();
    Utils.sendTrackerDetails(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    AppRate.with(this)
            .setInstallDays(1) // default 10, 0 means install day.
            .setLaunchTimes(4) // default 10
            .setRemindInterval(2) // default 1
            .setShowLaterButton(true) // default true
            .setDebug(false) // default false
            .setOnClickButtonListener(new OnClickButtonListener() { // callback listener.
                @Override
                public void onClickButton(int which) {
                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), Integer.toString(which));
                }
            })
            .monitor();

    // Show a dialog if meets conditions
    AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);


    if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only))
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);

    if (PreferenceManger.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getBooleanPreference(Constants.TAG_FIRST_USE)) {
        if (isRooted() == true) {
            Log.e("Device Rooted", "Device Rooted");
            showAlert();
        } else {
            Log.e("Device UnRooted", "Device UnRooted");
        }
        PreferenceManger.getInstance(MainActivity.this).putBooleanPreference(Constants.TAG_FIRST_USE, false);
    }

    mClientSpaceButton = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.esapce_client_button);
    mClientSpaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!Application.ismIsConnected())
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                //switchActivityWithLoginVerified("");
                //addFragment(new AuthentificationFragment(), null, AuthentificationFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
            else
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompteActivity.class));
        }
    });
    mLayoutSimulationPlacement = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.simulation_placement_layout);
    mLayoutSimulationPlacement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addFragment(new SimulationPlaFragment(), null, SimulationPlaFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);

        }
    });

    mLayoutReclamation = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_reclamation);
    mLayoutReclamation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });

    mLayoutAgence = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_agence);
    mLayoutAgence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MapFragment.Status = Constants.TAG_CLASS_AGENCE;

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(getRes(), MapFragment.newInstance(), "MapFragment");
            Log.e("created", "fragment");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    mLayoutGAB = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_gab);
    mLayoutGAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MapFragment.Status = Constants.TAG_CLASS_DAB;
            addFragment(new MapFragment(), null, MapFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
        }
    });


    mLayoutTmmHistory = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tmm_layout);
    mLayoutTmmHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFragment(new TMMFragment(), null, TMMFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    mLayoutSimulationCredit = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.simulation_credit);
    mLayoutSimulationCredit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFragment(new SimulationCreditFragment(), null, SimulationCreditFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);

        }
    });

    mLayoutTauxChange = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_change);
    mLayoutTauxChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addFragment(new TauxChangeFragment(), null, TauxChangeFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    mLayoutProduits = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_produits);
    mLayoutProduits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFragment(new ListeProduitsFragment(), null, ListeProduitsFragment.class.getCanonicalName(), false, MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    mLayoutVisite = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_visite);
    mLayoutVisite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(Constants.PDF_NAME, "visite_guidee.html");
            addFragment(
                    new WebViewFragment(),
                    bundle,
                    WebViewFragment.class
                            .getCanonicalName(), true, MainActivity.this
            );

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything that might be wrong but perhaps posting more info - xml, event method, fragment's oncreate/oncreateview.  `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is a little worrying about the overall architecture.

Comment: i'll edit the posted code, but what is really confusing is the fact that the second click works fine 

i've tried using commit(), and commitNow() same result !!

Comment: Show your activity onCreate code

Answer (score 0):

Silly Mistake of my part, it was due to the async task doInBackgroundMethod, found a catch block restarting the activity.